# tmux configuration: command output substitution doesn't

Tags: configuration, tmux, macos, syntax

I am trying to make parts of my `.tmux.conf` file conditional depending on the kind of system I'm on. For a start, I want one part to only be processed on MacOS.

The man page says that I can use the `#(COMMAND)` syntax to substitute the output of `COMMAND` in formats, so in particular in conditions. So I'm trying this:

```
%if "#{==:#(/usr/bin/uname -s),Darwin}"
CONF-COMMANDS
%endif
```

But no luck, `CONF-COMMANDS` are ignored on Mac. I have verified, of course, that "Darwin" is indeed the output of `uname -s`. As you can see, I'm using the absolute file name to eliminate any `PATH` problems. I have also verified that the trivial condition `%if "#{==:Darwin,Darwin}"` in fact works. So I must be doing something wrong regarding the syntax. What is it?

Comment: #299804 seems closely related, however, as I pointed out, I'm using the full name `/usr/bin/uname` , so it cannot be a `PATH` issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling you are running into a situation described in the man page:

> When constructing formats, tmux does not wait for `#()` commands to finish; instead, the previous result from running the same command is used, or a placeholder if the command has not been run before.

You can demonstrate this from within a Tmux session with:

```
tmux display-message -p "#(uname -s)"
```

Which should return `<'uname -s' not ready>`.

Consider using `if-shell` as an alternative to `%if` for this:

```
tmux if-shell '[ "$(uname -s)" = "Darwin" ]' "CONF-COMMAND; CONF-COMMAND2; ..."
```

Under Tmux 3.2a, the syntax is somewhat cleaner:

```
tmux if-shell '[ "$(uname -s)" = "Darwin" ]' {
  CONF-COMMAND1
  CONF-COMMAND2
}
```

Not tested on Mac, but confirmed to work with WSL/Ubuntu/Bash.  I think it should work as-is with Mac/Zsh.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. Interesting design there by tmux.